# it gives me an incorect syntax error 'vehiclereg'

Tags: c#

```
string Update = "UPDATE VehicleReport" +
                        "SET VehicleReg ='"+textBox1.Text+"',CurrentOdometer ='"+textBox5.Text+"',NextService ='"+textBox6.Text+"'" +
                        "WHERE Vehiclenum ='"+comboBox1.Text+"' ;";

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=FleetTrackingDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Update, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Updated");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception f)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(f.Message, "ERROR");
        }
```

Comment: There's a danger of SQL injections here, please parameterize your UPDATE statement and validate user input.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @marc_s I agree with you, but I just wanted to mention that I love that the code in that URL isn't even syntactically valid.

Comment: Hey OP, any answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

At least this is not correct:

```
string Update = "UPDATE VehicleReport" + "SET ...
```

you need to add a space between VehicleReport and Set

```
string Update = "UPDATE VehicleReport " + "SET....
```

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces

```
"UPDATE VehicleReport" +
   " SET VehicleReg ='"+textBox1.Text+"',CurrentOdometer ='"+textBox5.Text+"',NextService='"+textBox6.Text+"'" +
   " WHERE Vehiclenum ='"+comboBox1.Text+"' ;";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is missing space after table name :

```
string Update = "UPDATE VehicleReport"
string Update = "UPDATE VehicleReport "
```

and the same before `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 string Update = "UPDATE VehicleReport SET VehicleReg ='"+textBox1.Text+"',CurrentOdometer ='"+textBox5.Text+"',NextService ='"+textBox6.Text+"'" + " WHERE Vehiclenum ='"+comboBox1.Text+"' ;";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really shocked there are 4 answers but nobody mentioned about parameterized sql and SQL Injection attacks but anyway..

As others mentioned, you need spaces before your `SET` and `WHERE` words.

But more more more important is, **DON'T USE THIS WAY**. When you use string concatenations in your queries, your code will be open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead of this, you should always use [`parameterizezd queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

For example;

```
string Update = "UPDATE VehicleReport SET VehicleReg = @vehiclereg, CurrentOdometer = @current, NextService = @next WHERE Vehiclenum = @vehiclenum;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Update, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehiclereg", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@current", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@next", textBox6.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehiclenum", comboBox1.Text);
```